# Can sed be used with find to print Fields and Folder Name

Tags: bash, sed, find

This small script :

```
touch ilFldsN9LS.txt
ls -l | grep "^d" > /home/userB/PLAY/LibTESTxOutputFiles/ilFldsN9LS_testTEST.txt
```

produces file content of this format:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 userB userB 4096 Mar 23 22:40 BASH_Collection_FolderNESTY
drwxr-xr-x 2 userB userB 4096 Mar 24 17:33 BASH_Collection_Functionality
```

What I wish to achieve is to get output very much like the above, but using   find.
Turning to the use of *find*, this script: (which unlike the one previous, is recursive)

```
find . -type d \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec ls -ld {} \; | grep "^d" |\
| tee -a /home/UserB/PLAY/LibTESTxOutputFiles/ilFldsR9FB.txt
```

produces file content of this format:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 24 17:33 ./BASH_Collection_Functionality
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04 ./LibTESTxOutputFiles/AdditionalTESTresults
```

adding some AWK to the script, like so:

```
find . -type d \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec ls -ld {} \; | grep "^d" | awk '{ sub(/\.\//, " ");print}'\
| tee -a /home/innocentxlii/PLAY/LibTESTxOutputFiles/ilFldsR9FB.txt
```

produces output with the ****  ./    ***** stripped from the front of the path
and pads the gap with an extra space to ease reading:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 24 17:33  BASH_Collection_Functionality
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  LibTESTxOutputFiles/AdditionalTESTresults
```

Where I have gotten stuck, is I have been trying to use *sed* to keep the Fields, but to
have only the last Folder in the path, listed.  For example the last item above would be:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  AdditionalTESTresults
```

Ideas? I tried literally dozens of *sed* variants but have realized something must be
wrong with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need `sed`, you can do it all with `awk`

```
find . -type d \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec ls -ld {} \; | 
  awk '{n=split($NF,a,"/"); sub($NF, " "a[n])}1'
```

- `grep "^d"` is redundant since you are already finding directories with `find . -type d`

---

**awk** Explanation:

- `n=split($NF,a,"/")` splits the last field (denoted by `$NF`) by `/` and assigns it to array `a`
- `n` gives the length of the array
- `a[n]` will therefore return the string following the last `/` (i.e. the inner most directory)
- `sub($NF, " "a[n])` replaces the last field (denoted by `$NF`) with a space for padding (as per example) + inner most directory (denoted by `a[n]`)
- `awk '{...}1'` the `1` outside the awk is the same as `print`

---

EDIT: RE: for cases where directory contain spaces in name

```
find . -type d \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec ls -ld {} \; | 
    awk -F '[0-9]+:[0-9]+ ' '{n=split($NF,a,"/"); sub($NF, " "a[n])}1'
```

- specifying the input separator with `-F '[0-9]+:[0-9]+ '` (for modification time) will ensure the last field (`$NF`) is the file name -- regardless whether or not it contain spaces in the directory name

Comment: This is encouraging, now I am studying to see if I can finesse it to handle cases where the folders have spaces in their names.  But this get 85% of the job done without dragging sed into it.  My bad, did not clarify originally about spaces.

Comment: @MountainMan Although I'm still a little fizzy with regards to what you meant about spaces, I have now made an edit so that now the code should work for directories containing spaces in its name.

Comment: Strong work! it is handling it all now.  Guess who wants to learn more awk now. Moi.

Answer (score 1):

How about this: `sed -r 's/(.* )(.*)\/(.*)$/\1\3/g'`

Check my test runs below:

```
$ echo  "drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4" | sed -r 's/(.* )(.*)\/(.*)$/\1\3/g'
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir4

$ echo  "drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir1/dir2/dir3" | sed -r 's/(.* )(.*)\/(.*)$/\1\3/g'
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir3

$ echo  "drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir1/dir2" | sed -r 's/(.* )(.*)\/(.*)$/\1\3/g'
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir2

$ echo  "drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir1" | sed -r 's/(.* )(.*)\/(.*)$/\1\3/g'
drwxr-xr-x 2 UserB UserB 4096 Mar 25 16:04  dir1
```

**NOTE:** Please note that there is a **`space`** After the 1st asterisks in the sed command

Comment: Very nice, the only case missed was in a path with a folder having spaces in the name, followed down one level by a folder with no spaces.  But your sed beat about 40 I was grinding out.  As noted above, sorry I didn't make it clear it needed to handle space/nospace.

Comment: Learning from your examples, I made this, which while brittle in that it would get one in trouble if the levels were like 10 deep or whatever, works for my directory~tree (space and non): sed 's,\(.*  \)\?\(.*/\)\?\(.*/\)\?\(.*/\)\?\(.*/\)\?\(.*/\)\?\(.*\)$,\1\7,g'

Comment: cut and past code into here and it mangles it.  hmmm.  but the concept works.

Comment: @MountainMan, if you find my answer helpful in any possible sense, then could you up-vote it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what about

```
sed 's|\./||'
```

that remove the first `./`, so in your line

```
find . -type d \( ! -iname ".*" \) -exec ls -ld {} \; | sed 's|\./||'
```